# How to generate address out of a seed phrase and a derivation path for Solana and some tokens?

Tags: rust, account, seed, address, private-key

I know how to generate addresses out of a seed phrase and a derivation path in Ethereum. And I need to do the same thing for Solana too. However, I've done a research and barely  found anything.

Also, because Solana tokens have their own addresses, I need to generate addresses for USDT and USDC as well.

How to do it?

And, every time the same seed phrase and derivation path are used, **the same private key** will get generated each single time. That is, even if I loose a private key of one of those address I'll generate, I'll be able to restore it. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Regarding keygen

The `solana-keygen` CLI tool that comes with the Solana suite includes a `recover` instruction that does what you need. Typically, you'll do:

```
$ solana-keygen recover -o key.json prompt://
```

And then enter your seed phrase.  The `prompt://` part defines the derivation path.

You can find more info about the different paths at https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/paper-wallet#hierarchical-derivation and the source code for `recover` at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/9d1c0c5a3cedd71803aa9abedc981d3addec8a88/keygen/src/keygen.rs#L644-L665

#### Regarding token accounts

For token accounts, you should typically use the "associated" token account for a given wallet pubkey.  This address is defined as:

```
    solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey::find_program_address(
        &[
            &wallet_address.to_bytes(),
            &spl_token::id(),
            &token_mint_address.to_bytes(),
        ],
        &spl_associated_token_account::id(),
    )
```

Source code for that is at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/6793256b9e876f7441bd53c9de2c62c1ed56f5db/associated-token-account/program/src/lib.rs#LL68C5-L75C6

And you can find a JS helper that creates and sends the transaction to create an associated token account at If you want to also create the account, you can use a helper like `createAssociatedTokenAccount` in JS https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/b33bcc055e0c8e46eb0272df001759ed516474a5/token/js/src/actions/createAssociatedTokenAccount.ts#L20

So given just a SOL wallet address, anyone can send any token to you by creating the destination account and transferring the tokens. For example, if the mint address is `9ZFqaARv56e73BCDf9JqEo5yfzjSA6S5oEFu7UjsFqsi`, and a wallet address is `9JvLuNcPw5Vjrnjrhkd8he2JrGUyK6XRU756U47j7WPd`, they will use `createAssociatedTokenAccount` to create the token account at address `2ahN1r3vLKKcSbJqXuQmW9fYy6toLJBxpG1rzHncVNp7`, and then transfer the tokens into that account.

If they try to send the tokens to your wallet `9JvLuNcPw5Vjrnjrhkd8he2JrGUyK6XRU756U47j7WPd`, the transaction will fail because it's a SOL wallet, and not a token account belonging to mint `9ZFqaARv56e73BCDf9JqEo5yfzjSA6S5oEFu7UjsFqsi`.

You can read more about the associated token account program at https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account

#### Regarding mints

To get mint addresses, you typically need to rely on some other service that stores them. For USDT, I search "USDT" in the Solana explorer search bar, and it gives me https://explorer.solana.com/address/Es9vMFrzaCERmJfrF4H2FYD4KCoNkY11McCe8BenwNYB

A mint is a Solana account that stores information related to a particular token -- the supply of tokens, the number of decimals, the mint authority, etc. It could be compared to an ERC-20 smart contract, but the important distinction is that Solana programs separate logic from state in different accounts, unlike Ethereum which stores it all in the same place.  On Solana, everyone uses the same SPL token program, but every token has a different mint account.

You can find more information in the docs at https://spl.solana.com/token

Comment: `The solana-keygen CLI tool that comes with the Solana suite includes a recover instruction that does what you need. Typically, you'll do:` -- I meant, "how to do it in Rust" ? Or in JS, Python

Comment: `For token accounts, you should typically use the "associated" token account for a given wallet pubkey.` --> what do you mean "should use"? For what? I've asked: how to generate an associated account for USDT/C for a new SOL account"? In Rust or JS as well

Comment: what is "Given the mint address,"? Where is it? What is for USDT, for instance?

Comment: Edited my answer to answer your additional questions

Comment: `To get mint addresses, you typically need to rely on some other service that stores them.` --> ok. But WHAT is mint address precisely? Is it the address of a token? Is it a separate address which each token has in addition to its own address?

Comment: If I on my side generate a SOL account **only**, will a third-party user who has no access to the private key of that SOL address always be able to send USDT, USDC ... to it? Meaning, he'd simply open **any wallet** and try to send USDT or USDC to that SOL address.  Will the coins arrive in **any case**, or not?

Comment: Edited with more answers

Comment: A third-party user can create an associated token account for **my** SOL account? Without access to my private key?

Comment: Yep! The associated token account program guarantees that it's owned by your SOL account, and that you can find it through the address derivation. I edited my answer again with a link to https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account so you can learn more about the program